# Areat Chart multi lines gradient colors

Tags: highcharts

Hi im working on gradient colors of highcharts ,when i have the multiple lines the color of the gradient was still blue,it showulld be based on the legend color , i have tried many thing but that didnt worked,
       [Js Fiddle link][1]

```
 [1]: https://jsfiddle.net/GnanaSagar/0etnkqa7/2/
```

Answer (score 1):

You must define the gradient for each serie and not in the plotOptions like this :

```
  series: [{
    name: 'USA',
    data: [
      6, 11, 32, 110, 235,
      369, 640, 1005, 1436, 2063, 3057, 4618, 6444, 9822, 15468
    ],
    fillColor: {
      linearGradient: {
        x1: 0,
        y1: 0,
        x2: 0,
        y2: 1
      },
      stops: [
        [0, Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]],
        [1, Highcharts.Color(Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]).setOpacity(0).get('rgba')]
      ]
    },
  }, {
    name: 'USSR/Russia',
    data: [
      5, 25, 50, 120, 150, 200, 426, 660, 869, 1060
    ],
    fillColor: {
      linearGradient: {
        x1: 0,
        y1: 0,
        x2: 0,
        y2: 1
      },
      stops: [
        [0, Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1]],
        [1, Highcharts.Color(Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1]).setOpacity(0).get('rgba')]
      ]
    },

  }]
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4m6bce9j/)

Comment: thanks for the response , is there any way that we can apply gradient color for the multiple lines from plotOptions object , not in the series  object

Answer (score 0):

You can also define your gradient colors as a `colors` property, for example:

```
var colors = ["#7cb5ec", "#434348", "#90ed7d", "#f7a35c", "#8085e9", "#f15c80", "#e4d354", "#2b908f", "#f45b5b", "#91e8e1"];

Highcharts.chart('container', {
    colors: (function() {
        var gradientColors = [];

        colors.forEach(function(color) {
            gradientColors.push({
                linearGradient: {
                    x1: 0,
                    y1: 0,
                    x2: 0,
                    y2: 1
                },
                stops: [
                    [0, color],
                    [1, Highcharts.Color(color).setOpacity(0).get('rgba')]
                ]
            })
        });

        return gradientColors;
    })(),
    ...
});
```

Live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ngzv6rhf/

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/colors